# CSS selector for <select> chosen element, unless it is empty

Tags: css

I want to stylize a `<select>` for the case when not "please select" is chosen.

E.g.

```
select{
color: gray;
}

select:not-empty{
color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="">Empty, please gray</option>
  <option value="something">If selected, select in blue</option>
  <option value="something2">If selected, select in blue</option>
</select>
```

so if the option value is empty -> gray

option value not empty -> blue

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/dLxezv

what do I want?
this:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `<select onfocus="colorchange()">` Then `function colorchange(){ document.getElementsByTagName("select").style.color = "blue";}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5's validation can help you out here. Specifically, you need to make the `select` be required. Then use the `:valid` pseudo class to do the styling.

**Keep in mind that `value=""` (undefined) is NOT valid. Any string IS valid so you can use this to your advantage.**

Here's an example:

```css
select {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
select:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
}

select:valid {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select required>
<option value="">Empty value isn't valid</option>
<option value="1">Valid option</option>
<option value="2">Another valid option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there any similarly simple way to achieve this if the `select` field is not required?

Comment: @user3250386 that depends on your needs. If you don't use an HTML form/input type submit, then the "required" doesn't really mean anything. Eg if you use JS to collect and process the form then the required attribute becomes a CSS-only structure and doesn't block submission. With strict HTML forms with optional selects, I'm not aware of an easy solution.

Comment: @user3250386 as I think about it. Using `pattern="^(?!\s*$).+"` (non blank string) should trigger the `:valid`. That said I've never tried it on a select. I don't know if the pattern validation will work there.